# Radio buttons with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of div's:

```
<div class='option'>
    <span>here is a label for one pair of radio buttons</span>
    <a href='#' rel='radio' class='on'>On</a>
    <a href='#' rel='radio' class='off'>Off</a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to toggle between these two classes ('off' and 'on') using jQuery.

```
<script>; 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("a[rel='radio']").click(function(){
      if($(this).attr('class')=='on'){
        //make $(this) have class 'off'
        //make the other a in *this* div have class 'on'

      } else {
        //make $(this) have class 'on'
        //make the other a in the div have class 'off'
      }

  });
});
</script>
```

How can I turn the commented psuedo-code into real-world jQuery?

Comment: IMO the radio with class `on` should do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this;

```
$("a[rel='radio']").click(function(){
   $(this).siblings('a').andSelf().toggleClass('on off')
});
```

Comment: This is close too! Though, it's adding a class to the span as well :(

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour you describe differs from standard radio buttons, but it can be as follows: http://jsfiddle.net/BJGKH/.

```
$("a[rel='radio']").click(function(){
   // this and sibling - toggle both classes from each
   $(this).siblings("a[rel='radio']").addBack().toggleClass("on off");
});​
```

Comment: @VisioN: `andSelf` is so July! It's August with jQuery 1.8 :)

Comment: Exactly my vacations :) Came back and found that `:text`, `:checkbox` and `size()` (!!!) are deprecated. Seems it's not all the news...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("a[rel='radio']").click(function(){
      if($(this).attr('class')=='on'){
        $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('off').addClass('on');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('on').addClass('off');
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: This is SOO close!!!! But, I just updated my question (forgot to add the span) - which is now inheriting the new class with the 'siblings' selector